# Insert lines at specific location in file using perl script

Tags: regex, perl, perl-module

Want to add a new line in a file using perl script. I have tried but no luck

```
 if($correctedContents[$i] ~= /second line/){
 @data = $correctedContents[$i]
  push (@data, '\n TEST Line');
```

For example: add a "TEST Line" into a file whenever it find 'second line' line.

file1.txt,

```
first line
second line
third line

first line 
second line 
third line
```

.....

After added a new line 
expected output:

```
first line
second line
TEST Line
third line

first line 
second line 
TEST Line
third line
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: using if condition i found the 'second line', then assigned to a array. finally i used push command to add a line but it was not worked

Comment: Could you please go through the answers which you have received since [@dave cross](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47753759/4251338) mentioned already `Tie::File` module in his answer. There is a few samples available in search engine based on the modules.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't really shown us enough of your code for us to be very much help. But, in particular, you haven't shown any code where you write the changed data back to an output file.

In general, tasks like this boil down to three stages:

1. Read data from file.
2. Update data in some way.
3. Write changed data back to file.

One common approach is to have two filehandles open - one to your input file and another to a new output file. That makes it simple to process the file a line at a time.

```
while (<$input_fh>) {
  if (this is a line you need to change) {
    # make changes to line (which is in $_)
    # Perhaps print an extra line here.
  }
  print $output_fh $_;
}
```

Another approach (which trades speed for ease of use) is to use the [Tie::File](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::File) module (which is part of all Perl distributions since 5.8).

As always, the [Perl FAQ](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq.html) is a good place for more information. In this case, you probably want to look at [perlfaq5](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html), which contains the question [How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change%2C-delete%2C-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file%2C-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file%3F)

**Update:** You already have one (slightly problematic) Tie::File-based solution. So here's mine:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;

tie my @lines, 'Tie::File', 'somefile.txt'
  or die "Can't tie file: $!\n";

for (@lines) {
  $_ .= "\nTEST line" if $_ eq 'second line';
}
```

Comment: i dont want to change the existing line. Need to add a new line

Comment: dont want print the output in display, need to insert a line into a file

Comment: @Beginner Dave showed you here to do exactly that. It seems that you need to perhaps start by [learning some perl](http://perl-begin.org/) and perhaps you would understand more what has been said here.

Comment: And if you took the time to read my answer and the document that I linked to, then you would realise that I have explained how to do everything you ask. If you have questions about my answer, then feel free to ask them. But don't just assume I haven't answered your question.

Comment: @DaveCross Please check the comment from the OP in my answer

Comment: we cant do without Tie::File ?

Comment: @Beginner: I never said that. And I'm not sure where you got that idea from. Did you read the FAQ link I gave you?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Tie::File` can get the output what you have expect

```
use Tie::File;

my $inputFile = "test.txt";

my @array;
tie @array, 'Tie::File', $inputFile or die "Error: Couldn't tie the \"$inputFile\" file: $!";
my $len = join "\n", @array;

if($len=~m/second line/i) {  $len=~s/second line/$&\nTEST Line/ig;  }

@array = split/\n/, $len;
untie @array;
```

`Tie::File` will replace the string in a same input file.

Comment: 1. Using `||` instead of `or` here might lead to precedence issues. 2. Using `join` and `split` seems a very strange approach. 3. You haven't added a line, you have overwritten it.

Comment: @DaveCross: #1 will update in answer. #2. I don't know how to change instead of `join/split` using in code. #3. _Tie::File will replace the string in a same input file._ I have mentioned this.

Comment: You could fix your solution by changing the substitution to: `s/second line/second line\nTEST line/`. Because currently, your answer doesn't do what @beginner asked for. I have no idea why he accepted it.

Comment: Update your question please _for my case_

Comment: @ssr1012: His question already explains why your solution does work. He wants a new line inserted after the lines that match `/second line/`. Your code replaces the line, it doesn't add a new line. And my comment above explains how to fix that.

Comment: @Beginner: If this answer doesn't work for you, why have you accepted it?

Comment: @Beginner: Please accept the davecross answers below.

Comment: suppose i want to search the 'second' word in a file if it is not there add 'second line' after the 'first line'. how we can do that

Comment: @Beginner: If you have new requirements to add, then please don't add them as comments. It's best to raise a new question.

Comment: If raise some people dont like me then they are doing downvote for that

Comment: @Beginner: People aren't downvoting your questions because they don't like you. People are downvoting your questions because your questions are vague and badly-explained. Luckily, it's pretty easy to fix that.

Comment: i have altered this questions. can you give some sample code of it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161028/discussion-between-beginner-and-dave-cross).